# Does a referenced query result in fetching the data again?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In Power query I have a query fetching data from tblSales and performing row filtering on amount>100.

I want to reuse this query for another query. There are 2 options i have: duplicate or reference.

In duplicate the steps from the query are brought into the new query.

Where as in reference, the new query references the original query.

I right clicked on the original query and selected reference. Then added additional row filters. This new query that is generated, does it reuse the data fetched by original query?

Comment: Run [DAX Studio](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/capturing-power-bi-queries-using-dax-studio/#:~:text=%20Capturing%20Power%20BI%20queries%20using%20DAX%20Studio,your%20report.%20Keeping%20DAX%20Studio%20open,...%20More) and check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will run the query 'again'.

If you want to only load the data once, you need to wrap your base query in one of the Buffer functions.

- [Table.Buffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-buffer)
- [Binary.Buffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/binary-buffer)
- [List.Buffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-buffer)

[See here for more details](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/10/13/why-does-power-bi-query-my-data-source-more-than-once/)

In this scenario, the data is loaded twice:
[image]

In this Scenario, the data is loaded once ( Table.Buffer() on the base table ):
[image]
[image]

Comment: From the blog you posted "If you use Table.Buffer inside the Call Web Service query it will indeed buffer the result of the call to the web service into memory, but the data that is buffered cannot be shared between separate query executions – so the buffering happens three times, once for each time Call Web Service is evaluated by the three referenced queries."